# Checkstyle right curly brace configuration

Tags: java, checkstyle

Trying to figure out a way to make this code pass my Checkstyle rules:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * This is some comment.
 * @author John Doe
 */
public class Prog3a {

    /**
     * The main method executes and runs the program.
     * @param args takes in vargs from the CLI
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Program 3, John Doe");
        if(args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java prog3a infilename searchword");
            return;
        }

        try {
            final Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
            System.out.println("Opened file " + args[0] + " to search for '" + args[1] + "'");
            scan.close();
        } catch(java.io.FileNotFoundException e) { // need to make this valid
            System.err.println("File not found: " + args[1]);
        }
    }

}
```

With the current config, it wants this:

```
 }
 catch(...) {
```

Here's the section of the block config I'm working with:

```
<module name="RightCurly">
    <property name="option" value="alone" />
    <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE, CLASS_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_WHILE, LITERAL_DO, STATIC_INIT, INSTANCE_INIT" />
</module>

<module name="RightCurly">
    <property name="option" value="same" />
    <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_FINALLY" />
</module>
```

Full [checkstyle.xml here](http://hastebin.com/ilafiwiyoy.xml)

1. Is it possible to do this? If so, what do I need to change?
2. Is it "legal" to cascade rules in the Checkstyle config like I'm doing above?

Comment: If you're interested in following code formatting conventions, I would leave the rules alone and do as it suggests. In most languages that have one, I typically see the `catch` clause start on a separate line from the `try`'s closing brace. If you still want to do it, though, just a guess here, what happens if you move `LITERAL_TRY` to the other list?

Comment: @jpmc26 duly noted and that worked! That makes sense actually... You live and you learn